# svn hangs on checkout in Windows

Tags: windows, svn, ssh

Attempting to check out a repository using `svn checkout svn+ssh://USER@REPO .`

I have set my `%SVN_SSH%` variable to include the `-v` flag when calling `plink.exe`, and the last log I get is `Using username "USER".` After that the command line hangs indefinitely.

I get similar problems attempting to checkout the repository using TortoiseSVN and the Subversion integration in Intellij.

I have no problems connecting to the server using PuTTY or calling `plink` directly in the command line. Using the `-v` flag with `plink`, I get prompted for my password immediately after the line where it hangs using `svn checkout`.

I have Windows 7 Ultimate SP 1, svn version 1.8.13, plink release 0.60.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you *have* to use public key authentication for SVN to be able to use SSH in Windows properly.

There are a few tutorials online for how to do this, but the one that worked for me was [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20151004103052/http://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Windows).

The important difference, which I didn't find in other tutorials, was the usage of the `chmod` command to change access permissions to the public key file on the server.

Comment: Same here, couldn't get it to work with a regular password, while using keys does work.

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late to say, but i've had the similar problem.
In mine case the issue was in the command line of the `plink.exe`.

To properly fix all issues and do not type infinite logins and passwords:

1. Use `pageant.exe` to add the ppk key and avoid manual input of the password.
2. Use `SVN_SSH` environment variable with the `-l "<username>"` parameters to avoid manual input of the user name and avoid usage the username in the svn repository url.
3. Use `SVN_SSH` environment variable with the `-batch` parameter to avoid hangs in a script mode.

The resulting `SVN_SSH` environment variable should look like this:

`SVN_SSH="<path-to-plink>/plink.exe" -batch -l "<USER>"`

**warning**: backslash character in a path in the `SVN_SSH` variable is an escape character, you have to use a double to self escape it or replace it a forward slash - `/`.

But be careful with the `git svn` command, because the `SVN_SSH` variable can break the git with the message:

`Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://...': Error in child process: exec of '' failed: No such file or directory at .../Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 310.`

In that case you have to use the `ssh-pageant` from the `msys` or `cygwin` tools instead.

I've create another post with detailed description on how to do that step by step both for the `svn.exe` and `git.exe`: [How to use git-svn with svn+ssh url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345868/how-to-use-git-svn-with-svnssh-url/58641860#58641860)